# 4 variable swapping if not null

Tags: oracle, plsql

Stuck in one logic.
I have 4 variables,for example: var1,var2,var3,var4 (Their values can be null also.but at least one will be not null.)
Now I want to assign their values with not null values.

```
I meant that if Var1 is null then Var1 = var2 or var3 or var4 (which ever is not null).
if Var2 is null then Var2 should be var1 or var3 or var4 which ever is not null.

Case: if var1=null,var2=x,var3=null,var4=y
expected result is: var1=x or y,var2=x,var3=x or y,var4=y
```

I tried with if statement but somewhere stuck. I need to do this in Oracle plsql.
but logic in any language would help me.

I tried something like (but this wont wok):-

```
If (Var1 is null) then
Var1 =var2;
if(Var2 is null) then
var1=var3;
var2=var3;
if(Var3 is null) then
var1=var4;
var2=var4;
var3=var4;
```

Comment: Will only 1 variable be not null? Or could multiple be not null? In the latter case, how should that be handeled

Comment: "*I tried something like (but this wont wok)*" - Please provide your *actual* code.  This seems more like pseudocode. --- You did not properly define the expected behaviour. What, if more than one variable is not `null`? Which value should be assgned to `Var1`, if `Var2`, `Var3` and `Var4` are not `null`?

Comment: In case section i have given where many can be null but lease one will be not null.So Var1,var2,var3,var4 all can be null, but at least one will have some value. Turing- to your Q, var1=var2,var1=var3,var1=var4 anyhing is fine.

Comment: Search for `coalesce` function

Answer (score 3):

The following solution keeps each value unchanged if it is not null; otherwise it replaces it with the first non-null value found AFTER that variable (cycling back to the front if non-null values aren't found after the variable). Changing the order of the arguments in the calls to COALESCE will implement different rules for choosing the non-null value assigned to a variable that is NULL initially; however, the variable itself must always be the first argument, so that its value is preserved if it is non-NULL to begin with.

```
var1 := coalesce(var1, var2, var3, var4);
var2 := coalesce(var2, var3, var4, var1);
var3 := coalesce(var3, var4, var1, var2);
var4 := coalesce(var4, var1, var2, var3);
```

Note that `var1` in the second assignment is the value as already modified in the first assignment, but the result is still the same: each variable that was NULL initially is assigned the first non-NULL value in "cyclical order" considering the initial values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Consecutive `nvl` functions and a `nvl2` function located outer-most may be used in a SQL statement :

```
create table mytable1( var1 int, var2 int, var3 int, var4 int );
insert into mytable1 values(null,null,null,null);

create table mytable2( var1 int, var2 int, var3 int, var4 int );
insert into mytable2 values(null,null,null,10);

select nvl2(nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4),
            nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4),0) myValue
  from mytable1;

MYVALUE
-------
   0

select nvl2(nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4),
            nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4),0) myValue
  from mytable2;

MYVALUE
-------
  10
```

or a PL / SQL routine may be used, where `nvl` function do not need a select statement, but `nvl2` needs :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  var1 int;
  var2 int;
  var3 int :=  9;
  var4 ;
  var  int;
begin
  var := nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4);
  select nvl2(var,var,0) into var from dual;          
  dbms_output.put_line(' The result value is  '||var);

  var3 := null;

  var := nvl(nvl(nvl(var1,var2),var3),var4);
  select nvl2(var,var,0) into var from dual;          
  dbms_output.put_line(' The result value is  '||var||' if all values are null ');

end; 

 The result value is  9
 The result value is  0 if all values are null
```